# How to call a web/API service if the app is force closed and user does some actions from Actionable notifications? (iOS 10, Swift 3 )

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, swift3

I'm calling an Web/API service when user replying from the notification itslef but this all works only when the app is in the background mode. This is not working if the app is force-closed.

Using this for creating actionable actions:

`UNNotificationAction and TextInputNotificationAction`

Using this config for API calls:

`var dataTask: URLSessionDataTask?
 let currentSession = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)`

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: If the app is force closed then it is dead; it can't execute any code.

Comment: @Paulw11 we can do this with actionable notifications. Like reply from the notification itself. like whatsapp, telegram does. but i'm not able to figure this out how to do this on iOS 10, swift 3.

Comment: VoIP applications can use PushKit; this allows a silent push notification to re-launch an app (e.g. if a user is receiving a call in a VoIP app, it is probably a good thing that iOS relaunches that app), but if you use standard remote notifications then your app is not relaunched

Answer (score 0):

Read this doc, Apple say app can't be relaunched after force close

> Understanding When Your App Gets Launched into the Background

[link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)